# Blank Page is displaying while running particular content item

Tags: presentation

One specific content item is not rendering, showing blank page.

When we check log found below exception:

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message: The Sitecore.Client.ContentDatabase is null.
>   Source: Sitecore.Kernel
>      at Sitecore.Client.get_ContentDatabase()
>      at Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference.ParseRules(XmlNode configNode, RenderingItem renderingItem)
>      at Sitecore.Layouts.RenderingReference.ParseSettings(XmlNode configNode)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.CustomizeRenderingProcessor.GetRenderingReference(Rendering rendering, Language language, Database database)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.Personalize.Evaluate(CustomizeRenderingArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func `2 resultGetter)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.CustomizeRendering.Process(GetRendererArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetRenderer()
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Renderer()
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.ToString()
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.InitializeProfiling.StartProfiling(RenderRenderingArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.InitializeProfiling.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)

Any suggestion to figure out this issue.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with one of your renderings (or a rule on a rendering). Try removing them one by one to figure out which one..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ParseRules` method uses this code to pass proper database to `RuleFactory`:

```
renderingItem != null ? renderingItem.Database : Client.ContentDatabase
```

If it tries to pass `Client.ContentDatabase` (that's in your exception stack trace) it means that `renderingItem` is null.

So it looks like either one of the renderings which was added to presentation details of that page no longer exists or maybe it was not published to `web` database yet.

Check the presentation details of the page in `master` database first. See which of the renderings has some rules assigned. Then switch to `web` database. Check if that rendering is also in the `web` database.

If none of the components has rules assigned, check all the renderings if all of their definitions are present in `web` database.

Answer (score 0):

Just for explaining exact fix. This issue was due to newly added renderings were not ***published*** to `web` DB.

Once publish required renderings, content item started showing proper content.

[image]